# How to have a callback function called onTap, another onTapDown, and another onTapUp without overlap?

Tags: flutter, gesture

I have this UI: [image]
When user taps on right side we go to the next story, left we go to previous and holding down anywhere should stop the automatic loading on top. I am currently using `GestureDetector`s and using the three callbacks

- `onTap` To go to next or previous story
- `onTapDown` To pause the loader
- `onTapUp` To resume the loader

The problem is `onTap` gets called with `onTapUp` so when I try to pause for example by holding down on the right side, it would immediately go to the next story after I lift my finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the below solution, I tested it and it works quite well in your case.

Below is a custom `GestureDetector` widget that allows us to set the duration for `onLongPressStart` and `onLongPressEnd`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class CustomGestureLongPress extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? child;
  final Duration duration;
  final GestureLongPressStartCallback onLongPressStart;
  final GestureLongPressEndCallback onLongPressEnd;
  final VoidCallback? onLongPress;

  const CustomGestureLongPress({
    super.key,
    this.child,
    required this.duration,
    required this.onLongPressStart,
    required this.onLongPressEnd,
    this.onLongPress,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
        LongPressGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(
              () => LongPressGestureRecognizer(duration: duration), (instance) {
                instance.onLongPress = () {
                  print("Parent onLongPress");
                  onLongPress?.call();
                };
                instance.onLongPressStart = (details) {
                  print("Parent onLongPressStart");
                  onLongPressStart.call(details);
                };
                instance.onLongPressEnd = (details) {
                  print("Parent onLongPressEnd");
                  onLongPressEnd.call(details);
                };
              },
        ),
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}`
```

And the usage of the custom widget

```
CustomGestureLongPress(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            onLongPressStart: (_) {
              //TODO Pause the loader
            },
            onLongPressEnd: (_) {
              //TODO Resume the loader
            },
            child: Stack(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      //TODO Go to previous story
                    },
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50.w,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      //TODO Go to next story
                    },
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50.w,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                    )
                  )
                ]
            ),
          )
```

Comment: It works great, but I thought if two gesture detectors overlap the child wins, so how is the child `GestureDetector`'s `onTap` not getting called?

Comment: You are right. About `GestureDetector`, only the first gesture recognizer to enter the gesture arena will win. The `onLongPress` is the first recognizer to enter the arena, not the `onTap` recognizer. You can add more callback handlers for `onLongPressDown` and `onTapDown` to see it.
Then you may wonder if it is so the child GestureDetector `onLongPress` should be called instead of the parent `onLongPress` right?
The key is the customize `onLongPress` `duration`. Duration for parent `onLongPress` is `200ms`, shorter than the default value of the children. That makes the parent win.

Comment: Try to change the parent's `onLongPress` duration to `600ms`, now the child's `onLongPress` will be the winner.

Answer (score 1):

A **tap** gesture consists of a tap-down followed "immediately" by a tap-up gesture. Consequently, as you indicate, if you combine those callbacks they will overlap each other.

What you are looking:

- For **pausing** the loader: `onLongPressStart` (or `onLongPressDown`)
- For **resuming** the loader: `onLongPressEnd` (or `onLongPressUp`)

This will allow differentiating between long-presses and taps.

Comment: I did consider this but I didn't want long pressing, so my solution was the `RawGestureDetector` to customize the long press duration

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a combination of onHorizontalDragStart, onHorizontalDragEnd, and onHorizontalDragUpdate instead of onTapDown and onTapUp. This will allow you to differentiate between taps and drags, providing more control over the pause and resume actions.

```
GestureDetector(onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
  },
  onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  },
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
    // You can handle swipe gestures here if needed
  },
```

Comment: I don't want dragging, I want the pause to happen when holding down not dragging horizontally (Exactly like Instagram stories)

Answer (score 0):

The more simple and customizable approach is using [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) for delaying tap interaction.

This is the simple workaround to demonstrate:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  
  final isPaused = ValueNotifier(false);
  Timer? timer;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: isPaused,
          builder: (_, paused, child) {
            return ColoredBox(
              color: paused ? Colors.red : Colors.yellow,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (_) {
              print('> onTapDown');
              timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
                isPaused.value = true;
                print('Story paused');
              });
            },
            onTapUp: (_) {
              print('> onTapUp');
              if (isPaused.value) {
                print('Resume current story');
              } else {
                print('Go to the next story');
              }
              timer?.cancel();
              isPaused.value = false;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: demo]

You can reusing this widget to achieve the story next-prev navigation by layouting this widget into a row to capture left and right area for story navigation.

Maybe it could be an alternative solution for your problem, Thanks